# String parameter placeholder

Tags: c#, string, parameters

```
        string str = "({{0}})";
        int i = 0;
        string str2 = string.Format(str, i++);
        string str3 = string.Format(str, i++);
```

why is str3 ({0}) instead of ({1})?

Comment: Well, I need those. ({1}), not (1).

Comment: I think you are asking `why is str3 ({0}) instead of (1)?`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, No. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You escaped the curly braces so they have no special meaning. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx):

> To specify a single literal brace character in format, specify two leading or trailing brace characters; that is, `"{{"` or `"}}"`.

You can simplify your program and still demonstrate the problem:

```
Console.WriteLine("{{0}}", 1);
```

Output:

```
{0}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/WUQOp)

---

To get the desired output you need to use `{{` followed by `{0}` and then finally `}}`:

```
string str = "({{{0}}})";
```